# Assigning variable on condition

Tags: xslt

I would like to assign a variable like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="dateTime" select="script:DateConversion(/date/field,'yyyyMMddHHmm','s',0)"/>
```

(script:DateConversion is a function in an external dll)

The problem is that the format field sometimes should be 'yyMMddHHmm' based on the value of /date/fieldformat

Any ideas on how to do that?

In psudo-code:

```
if /date/fieldformat = 1 then
  dateTime = script:DateConversion(/date/field,'yyyyMMddHHmm','s',0)
else if /date/fieldformat = 2 then
  dateTime = script:DateConversion(/date/field,'yyMMddHHmm','s',0)
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if thats what you mean but you can have conditional statement within `<xsl:variable>`

For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="dateTime">
    <xsl:if test=[check date format]>
        <xsl:value-of select="script:DateConversion(/date/field,'yyyyMMddHHmm','s',0)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test=[check date format]>
        <xsl:value-of select="script:DateConversion(/date/field,'yyyyMMddHH','s',0)"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

You can also use `<xsl:choose>` within variable if that suits better.